# Hide a Column in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to hide a column in SharePoint 2010 list based on Users.

When user submit a request the status column should be hidden and the value set as pending.

When Admin logged in he/she should able to edit the status.

Is there any way I can achieve this without writing CUSTOM CODE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to archive this without programming. The easiest is to Create a new view for the list or use webpart to view the content for the other users.

Comment: When you create a new view and you click (Add new document) the field that you unchecked will still appear in the form..what I want is to hide that field in the form list,, or may be if there is something called Column permessions..I dunno...Please help

Comment: You can use InfoPath to create a custom form. I am on holiday and just at my smartphone. So I am sorry that I can't get you a better example

Comment: There is not something as column permission cause for that are the views. There are just permissions per entry, but that should not be used for list greater 5000 entries

Comment: Thanks alot sra, I found a free tool that does the following
It includes :

   1. A tool to recursively delete sites
   2. A tool to create a list in multiple sites at once
   3. A tool to modify field settings - some internal settings that you cannot modify in the regular interface, and the option to modify lists with the same name in multiple sites at once
   4. A tool to push a web part to multiple sites (a specific page in each site) at once
   5. (in beta) a tool to manage list event hanlders (register and remove event handlers from lists)

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind, you can try the third-part tools, such as [BoostSolutions Column/View Permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html), [Infowise Smart List Pro](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListPro&src=smm). 
They are all good tools and can hide columns based on the conditions.